# How to Get a Headless Browser for Selenium (Firefox)?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, headless, headless-browser

So recently I was looking into trying to get a headless browser for Selenium for web scraping and I came upon this solution on multiple websites

```
from selenium import webdriver

geckodriver = 'C:UsersgraysonDownloadsgeckodriver.exe'

headOption = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
HeadOption.setheadless()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, firefox_options=headOption)

browser.get('https://www.duckduckgo.com')

browser.save_screenshot('C:UsersgraysonDownloadsheadless_firefox_test.png')

browser.quit()
```

However I was still getting errors while trying to use the properties and arguments in this code.From what I can tell they seem to be outdated. What is the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

geckodriver = 'C:UsersgraysonDownloadsgeckodriver.exe'

headOption = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
headOption.**add_argument('-headless')**

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver, **options**=headOption)

browser.get('https://www.duckduckgo.com')

browser.save_screenshot('C:UsersgraysonDownloadsheadless_firefox_test.png')

browser.quit()
```

The asterisk mark the differences. Basically Selenium doesn't like the '.setheadless' property anymore and has replaced the "firefox_options" argument with just "options"

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 4):

Don't copy paste code from the net with out understanding what it does.

firefox option doesn't have any method like setHeadless, but has a property called headless

```
headOption = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
headOption.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=headOption)
```

you can set headless like this or by passing argument

```
headOption = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
headOption.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=headOption)
```

Both does the same thing , headless property pass the argument --headless under the hood